# Training a model in machine learning and predict some values

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, knn

I am almost new to machine learning. I have a biological dataset like-

```
index  position B   y
  1      1001   0  0.567
  2      1010   0  0.682
  3      1012   1  0.346
  4      1016   1   
  5      1020   1  0.875
  6      1040   0  
  7      1044   0  1.00
  8      1047   1  0.101
  9      1056   0  0.00
```

I am trying to predict the y values that are missing. I am using KNN regression for this. I have read that train-test-validation splitting is better than train-test splitting followed by cross validation. I have some question-

1. When i train my model, should i exclude the rows where y is not known?
2. How to workout with that validation and test set?
3. After i have trained my model, should i only take rows where y is not known and predict the values?
4. Is the accuracy and error rate using test dataset is the accuracy of my model?

I have a lot question. I wanted to figure these out watching tutorials but couldn't get a complete insight. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer one by one your questions

1. No, when you train a model, you should tell which target value is right for fixed features (the columns on your dataset). So you always use the target value y in the training phase.
2. Using cross-validation means to not waste your test set (**remember you can use it only once!**) and improve your training avoiding overfitting.
3. You should test your trained model with the test set. So you actually predict on your test set (that does not have target values) and you see the results.
4. The test set, if used once, provides you with an accuracy of the model. Mind that there are cases which the accuracy is pointless (*)

In the end, the process for training a model it's more or less this:

1. Split your dataset in 80% training set and 20% test set (or 70-30, depending on how many data you have)
2. From the training set, you build a training set and validation set using [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) (this is just a tip). (validation set of 10-15%)
3. You train your model with the training set and do validation (very important!) with the validation set.
4. Discard (and save somewhere else) the y column on the test set and use your trained model to predict the test set.
5. With the values it provides, you compute metrics (such as MSE) between these values and the once you saved at the previous step and see how good it's your model.

Remember that this is a guideline but it's much more complex. You will see it the more you get in the matter.

(*) For example, if you train your model with samples that are almost the same and the test set is composed of the 99% of samples that are similar and 1% that is different, you will get an accuracy of the 99%. That's a lot but it's useless since the model can predict only one class. So ofc mind each step depending on your case.

Comment: For the example dataset that i added here, should i remove row- 4 & 6 while training my model? And after i have checked the accuracy will i use my model only for rows 4 & 6 (taking them in a different file or array)?